# multiple python scripts write to one log file contains the date and time creation

Tags: python, logging

1. i want to run multiple python scripts (let say they are all start
   from a main script called `main.py`) which will write to **one log
   file** contains the **date and time creation**, also, I need the
   logger to be written to the console and the file. **python 2**.

   I tried many different ways with no success,

   Example:

   `main.py` : run scripts `python1.py` and `python2.py` one after one, and
   the three python scripts will write to the same log file which have
   a date and time in it's name, and the log showed on the console
   while running.
2. Also, Is something like this can be done through a python script
   which is apareted from these files? for example 4th file called log_to_one_file.py?

if somebody know how to make it happen - i will be glad to know...

Comment: Are you using the Python `logging` module? You should! Read the documentation and tell us what exactly did not work.

Comment: share the code of main and show how you use other py modules

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html):

> Multiple calls to logging.getLogger('someLogger') return a reference to the same logger object. This is true not only within the same module, but also across modules as long as it is in the same Python interpreter process. It is true for references to the same object;

Comment: thanks, will think how to re-order my logger using your suggestion, will update... :)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a homework exercise, which assumes the non-existence of ready python modules.

In that case it will be better to check the python [file operations](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-file-handling) and create a fuction that receives as arguments the log content and the log file path, which appends to that file the contents, after prefixing the date and time. Then you can create a file in the same folder called `log_to_one_file.py`, place the function there, and then import it to your file you need logging using `from log_to_one_file import function`

In case a more plug-in solution is needed, a more advanced answer is that you could ovewrite the default sys.STDOUT variable and append a file streamer to that like that:

```
import sys
import sys

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open(path, "a")

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)  

    def flush(self):
        pass    

sys.stdout = Logger(path)
```

In the above solution wou can modify the message with a date and time prefix inside `write` method of the `Logger` class.
Then, after this piece of code has run, whenever you call `print` in your program, it will automatically write to the file and log to your console, using the formatting you have set it to have.

You can have a reading on Python context managers , if you want to apply the above solution in a more limited environment

Comment: wish it will be an homework... than copy paste from friend is better idea than trying to solve it :)  the second one i tried - but it will not log to the consol, just to the file...

Comment: I am glad I was able to help! Please consider upvoting or accepting as best answer, if I managed to answer your question adequately!